# Book about small people living hidden from humans in a big city

Tags: story-identification, books

About 10 years ago I read this book about small people (they were a different race than humans I think) who are living in a big English or American city. They hide from normal people and live in lost buildings or subway tunnels. I remember that the story was about some problems they had with the police or something.

Comment: Could this be the Borribles?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Borrible_Trilogy.  They had problems with the police - they called them 'woollies'.  They were children, so depends on how small you mean.  They lived in abandoned houses.

Comment: Do you recall how small the characters were? E.g. something like child-sized compared to adults, insect sized, somewhere in between?

Comment: Is it a children's book? If so, maybe it's one of Terry Pratchett's Nome / Bromeliad trilogy? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nome_Trilogy

Comment: YES it is the Borribles! I didnt think someone would guess it so fast. I really remembered almost nothing. Thank you very much @SpikeHolden and the others for your suggestions!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the [*Borribles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Borrible_Trilogy) – a trilogy of books by Michael de Larrabeti.  It features runaway children who become 'Borribles' (match: 'small people') in London ('big English … city') and live in abandoned houses ('lost buildings'). They hide from the police who they call 'Woollies'.

Their rivals are the 'Rumbles' who are a rather obvious parody of the Wombles (down to the names of their leaders).

Marketed as a young adult book, but very dark in its atmosphere and theme.

One of my favourite series and I own a copy on my shelf (not the new covers which look awful and ignore the fact that Borribles wear caps to hide their pointy ears). Would make a great TV/film series.

Comment: For some reason it really got stuck in my head over all the years. It is a really liberating feeling to know it now, thanks again :D I am looking forward to read it!

Comment: Is this name chosen deliberately to evoke [_The Borrowers_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Borrowers)?